# R: Replace a character in a string by index

Tags: r

How do you replace the nth character in an R string with something else?
For example:

```
x <- "Thas is spelled wrong!"
```

How do you change the 3rd character of the string to and "i" so it reads:
"This is spelled wrong!" instead?

Answer (score 5):

The substr function may be used for assignment as well as lookup. The following will work:

```
substr(x, 3, 3) <- "i"
```

I've been using substr for years without realizing it could be used this way as well! [feeling stupid]